Sharepoint Search is not fetching latest content
I tried for SharePoint 2010 Search is not fetching latest document / content.
Run full Crawl from SharePoint Central Admin
Run Incremental Crawl from SharePoint Central Admin.
But unable to track error where i got actual reason.
getting error:
An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser.
